# Migrating tmux sessions to another remote machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualhost, remote-server, tmux

I am trying to migrate my all tmux sessions from one remote machine to another machine.
Is there any thing like:

```
tmux export all-sessions > "remote-host"
```

Answer (score 0):

No - tmux can't move programs running on one machine to another.

Comment: can't we generate any yaml or json to list all sessions and panes and automate that file in another machine?
this is what i am trying to do but i have no clue how to do it

Comment: You just want the layouts not the programs that are in the panes? There is no builtin way. It would be possible to write a script to generate them using the `list-panes`, `list-windows`, `list-sessions` commands with their `-F` flag and recreate the layout using `new-session`, `new-window`, `split-window` but there is no existing solution that I know of. Perhaps something like https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect can do it, although I think it only works on the same machine.